# How can I get around <img src... causing broken image icon?

Tags: php, image

In PHP I am able to upload images to my database and display in a table. However a broken image icon is displayed in postings when there is no image. I was wondering how I could check for an image prior to displaying so I don't get the broken image icon. I have recently determined that the broken image icon is being caused by the image tag in my index.php file. I figured this out when commenting out code in my getImage.php file. I don't believe I can have an if statement in the middle of me echoing out a table. Help would be appreciated.

Code from my index.php file:

```
include('connect.php');
$query = 'SELECT * FROM forumPosts LEFT JOIN PostImages ON 
forumPosts.DATETIME = PostImages.ImageDATETIME ORDER BY replyIndex 
ASC';
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$posts = $statement->fetchAll();
$statement->closeCursor();
echo "<table>";
foreach ($posts as $post){
if ($post['post_type'] == "r"){
    $post_id = $post['post_id'];
        echo "<tr bgcolor='beige'><td>reply</td><td>". 
        $post['post_title'] . "</td ><td>". $post['post_body'] . "
        <img src='getImage.php?id=".$post['ID']."'>". "</td><td>". 
        $post['DATETIME']. "</td><td>". $post['replyIndex']. "</td>
        <td>".$post['post_type']."</td>";
```

And the getImage.php file:

```
<?php
include('connect.php');

$ID = $_GET['id'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM PostImages WHERE ID=:ID";
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->bindvalue(':ID', $ID);
$statement->execute();
$row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $row['image'];
```

Any idea how I can check for an image?
Code below is how images are stored.

```
<?php
if ($image_size == FALSE){
//echo "image_size = false";
header('Location: index.php');
} else {
$query = "INSERT INTO PostImages (name, image, ImageDATETIME) 
    VALUES (:image_name, :image, :DATETIME)";
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->bindvalue(':image_name', $image_name);
$statement->bindvalue(':image', $image);
$statement->bindvalue(':DATETIME', $DATETIME);
$statement->execute();
$statement->closeCursor();
}
?>
```

[image]

Comment: Wait, are you asking to check if the image is in the drive?

Comment: I want to check the database to see if there is an image so I don't get the broken image icon.

Comment: @MattMacy - Are you actually storing this image on your file system somewhere? The query above seems it just stores values in the DB. Could you give us a screen shot of the table with data?

Comment: Can you show how you generate the `$posts` array?

Comment: If you are doing a JOIN (which I assume you are to join posts and post images), then you should add an `if` statement that checks if a column exists that could only come from the PostImages table.

Comment: Thanks for that idea. I am not sure of how to go about doing that. if there is anymore you could tell me about that it would be helpful.

Comment: Does only the PostImages have an ID column? Or does the forumPosts have an ID column too?

Comment: I added an answer which should help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
include('connect.php');
$query = 'SELECT * FROM forumPosts LEFT JOIN PostImages ON 
forumPosts.DATETIME = PostImages.ImageDATETIME ORDER BY replyIndex 
ASC';
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$posts = $statement->fetchAll();
$statement->closeCursor();
echo "<table>";
foreach ($posts as $post){
if ($post['post_type'] == "r"){
    $post_id = $post['post_id'];
        echo "<tr bgcolor='beige'><td>reply</td><td>". 
        $post['post_title'] . "</td >";
        echo "<td>". $post['post_body'];
        if (!empty($post['ID'])) {
            echo "<img src='getImage.php?id=".$post['ID']."'>";
        }
        echo "</td><td>". 
        $post['DATETIME']. "</td><td>". $post['replyIndex']. "</td>
        <td>".$post['post_type']."</td>";
```

Explanation: Since you are joining forumPosts with the PostImages table, you need to check if column data exists that could only come from the PostImages column. So I added a `if` statement that checks if `ID` exists. Assuming this comes from the PostImages table.

Addendum: There is nothing wrong with putting an `if` statement in the middle of a table. That is how you dynamically generate the HTML structure. The only consideration should be that you don't generate invalid HTML, such as leaving out a closing tag (like `</td>`). But this `if` statement will only leave out the `<img>` tag if an image doesn't exist, and that won't make the table's HTML invalid.

Answer (score 0):

To extend on FirstOne's answer, you can use a basic logic check:

```
if (!empty($row['image']) {
    echo $row['image'];
} else {
    echo 'empty';
}
```

Inside the else, you could figure out what to do or display during the case of an empty `$row['image']` variable.

Comment: After re-reading, I don't think that's how the OP stores the image. Check the `src`. They pass the post ID to a page that will load the image. That way, the link will already be created and the page creating it doesn't know if the image exists.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Interesting architecture. If he's doing a query, then returning $row with the columns of his checked table, we should safely assume $row['image'] would be empty, right (unless I am further misunderstanding).

Comment: with that code added I get no display of an image. It should be so simple.

Comment: @MattMacy, you and me both! Having bit of trouble understanding your structure and how the images are stored (where, how, an in what format).

Comment: The image BLOB are stored in a database on my localhost